# Microsoft Excel 2010 the difference between two times in two different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Other answers helped but have a problem with the following

```
Start Time 23:56 End Time 0:32 difference is 36 minutes. 
Start Time 21:53 End Time 22:05 difference is 12 minutes.
```

What formula can I use to get the amount of minutes using a 24 clock time frame.  As I just want to enter my times and have Excel do the rest.

Hope this makes sense and someone can help with an answer.

Comment: If times can pass midnight, a simple solution is to store the date/time rather than just the time.  You can display just the time portion, but including the date in the value makes it a continuous variable that doesn't require any special manipulation (just subtract one from the other).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(B1-A1),MOD(B1-A1,1))
```

EG (and I've used different times to you)

```
      A         B         C
1    23:50    00:32     =IFERROR(DATEVALUE(B1-A1),MOD(B1-A1,1))
2    21:53    22:05     =IFERROR(DATEVALUE(B2-A2),MOD(B2-A2,1))
```

The result of C1 would be 00:42, and C2 would be 00:12

Answer (score 0):

With the start time in **A1** and the end time in **B1** consider:

```
=IF(B1>A1,B1-A1,1+B1-A1)*24*60
```

[image]